# Fatal error: Call to a member function getFullActionName() on null

Tags: product, magento-1, catalog

Iam geting the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getFullActionName() on
>   null in
>   /app/code/community/MageWorx/CustomOptions/Model/Catalog/Product/Option.php
>   on line 1627

And the Line#1627 is :

```
$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction()->getFullActionName();
```

Would be great if anyone can provide me the solution to this error.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace this code with:

```
$action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
if (!$action || $action->getFullActionName() == "catalog_category_view") {
    return parent::getProductOptionCollection($product);
}
```

**PS:** In case you got an error in the custom module, first I'll recommend drop a line to the vendor.

Answer (score 0):

try this, to get fullaction name in custom way.

```
    $request = Mage::app()->getRequest();
    $module = $request->getControllerModule();
    $module_controller = $request->getControllerName();
    $module_controller_action = $request->getActionName();

    $fullActionName = $module."_".$module_controller."_".$module_controller_action;
```